# События для динамически добавленных элементов, какой запрос сделать к DOM?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Здравствуйте. Вставляю новые элементы при клике на кнопку. Как при добавлении новых элементов сделать проверку у каких элементов есть событие, а у каких нет и навесить если нет.

```js
let row = document.querySelector(".row");
let btn = document.querySelector(".btn");
let photoGirls = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".row .img"));

class hoverImage {
  static mouseover () {
    this.classList.add("img--active")
  }
  static mouseout () {
    this.classList.remove("img--active")
  }
}

function jsonGirls() {
  let promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    let requestGirls = new XMLHttpRequest();
    requestGirls.open("get", "girls.json", true);
    requestGirls.send();
    requestGirls.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (requestGirls.readyState === 4) {
        if (requestGirls.status === 200) {
          let jsonGirl = JSON.parse(requestGirls.responseText);
          let loaded = +row.getAttribute("data-loaded-count");
          let nextLoaded = loaded + 5;
          if (nextLoaded >= jsonGirl.length) {
            btn.style.display = "none";
          }
          let jsonGirlCopy = jsonGirl.slice().splice(loaded, 5);

          row.setAttribute("data-loaded-count", nextLoaded);

          jsonGirlCopy.forEach(function (element) {
            let newPhotoGirls = `<div class="img" style="background-image:${element.img}"><div class="img-hover"><div class="img__title">${element.text}</div></div></div>`;
            row.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", newPhotoGirls);
          });
          resolve(requestGirls)
        } else {
          reject(requestGirls)
        }
      }
    }
  })
  return promise;
}

btn.onclick = function () {
  jsonGirls()
    .then(
      function(onFulfilled) {


      },
      function(onRejected) {
        alert("Загрузите ещё раз");
      }
    )
};

photoGirls.forEach(function (element) {
  element.addEventListener("mouseover", hoverImage.mouseover);
  element.addEventListener("mouseout", hoverImage.mouseout);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно таким способом задавать события:

```js
photoGirls.forEach(function (element) {
  element.onmouseover = hoverImage.mouseover;
  element.onmouseout = hoverImage.mouseout;
});
```

Если есть необходимость проверять, привязано ли уже к элементу такое событие, то можно это делать обычной проверкой на null:

```js
photoGirls.forEach(function (element) {
  if (!element.onmouseover) {
    element.onmouseover = hoverImage.mouseover;
  }
});
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/23arcx5o/7/ не работает :(